# Unable to implement MICE in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, imputation

I'm trying to use `statsmodels` package of MICE to impute values for my columns. I'm unable to figure out how exactly to use it. Whatever I run, it throws the error: `ValueError: variable to be imputed has no observed values`

Code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('contacts.csv', engine='c',low_memory=False)
from statsmodels.imputation.mice import MICEData as md
md(df)
```

Why am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

at least one of the columns in the generated data frame (hence csv) is empty.

Check the dataframe, maybe you have to clean it up/normalize.

Also, don't afraid to look into [the code base](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/imputation/mice.html#MICE).
What you are looking for is the `_split_indices` method of `MICEData`.